# How to make node.js automatically load config files

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line, config, configuration-files

In node.js, you can use 'require()'
to load your configuration files, but I am tired of having to do that on all my programs. Is there a way to make node.js automatically load config files?

Comment: Explicit is always better then implicit. Don't be lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found out you can do that by putting this in your '.bash_profile' or shell configuration file on a unix machine:

```
alias node='node -r ./config.js'
```